# Ошибка в форме авторизации

Tags: php, mysql

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Приветствие</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<?php
include_once 'connect.php';
?>
<body>
  <h3>Добро Пожаловать, Пользователь</h3>
<?php
  $form = true; 
  if (!IsSet($_POST['submit'])) { to_index('Простите, но сначала надо зарегистрироваться<br />') ;  $form=false; }
  if (Empty($_POST['login']) || Empty($_POST['pass'])) { echo to_index('Простите, но вы некорректно заполнили форму для входа на сайт.<br/><br/>Все поля формы обязательны для заполнения.<br/>'); $form=false; }
  //Тут идут проверки на валидность введенных данных
  // Если все проверки успешны, начинаем сессию, иницилизируем переменные
  session_start() ;
  $u_login=$_POST['login'] ;
  $u_pass=$_POST['pass'] ;
  //Выполняем проверку соответствия введенных данных.
  // Задаём переменные сессии
  $_SESSION['login']=$u_login;
  $_SESSION['pass']=$u_pass;
  $_SESSION['user']='user';
  // Инициализация админа
  if ($u_login=='admin' && $u_pass=='secret') {
    $_SESSION['user']='admin';
    header("Location: admin.php"); 
  }
    // Проверяем логин-пароль пользователя
    list($f_name, $last_name)= preg_split('/s+/', $n);
    if(empty($f_name) || empty($l_name)) { to_index('Логин состоит из пары Имя, пробел, Фамилия<br>') ; $form=false; }
    $user_db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_LOGIN, DB_PASS, DB_NAME)
    $query = "SELECT 1 FROM subscribes WHERE first_name='$f_name' and last_name=$l_name";
    $result = $user_db->query($query);
    $rows=mysqli_num_rows($data);
    mysqli_close($dbc);
    echo "Добро пожаловать на нашу учебную страничку, $obr $f_name $l_name.<br/><br/>";
    ?>
    <p><a href=user_lists.php>Редактировать свой список рассылки</a><p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `>_<` Где ошибка, какая ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Как минимум `session_start();` и `header("Location: admin.php");` нужно вызывать **ДО** любого вывода. Выполняйте сначала всю логику, а потом уже выводите HTML.

После `header` нужно ставить `exit` - иначе продожится выполнение скрипта.

Answer (score 1):

`$user_db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_LOGIN, DB_PASS, DB_NAME)` - забыл поставить точку с запятой в конце - `$user_db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_LOGIN, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);`.

`<p><a href=user_lists.php>Редактировать свой список рассылки</a><p>` - исправь на это
`<p><a href="user_lists.php">Редактировать свой список рассылки</a></p>`

Answer (score 0):

Пропустили точку с запятой 36 строка

```
$user_db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_LOGIN, DB_PASS, DB_NAME)
```